# How do I restrict SonarLint to analyse only spefic modules in a Project?

Tags: optimization, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I am trying to Implement the SonarLint plugin into my IntelliJ IDE.
We have a fairly huge code base and on running scan all projects, SonarLint ends up taking a lot of time, also If we want to find code smells and issues with only a specific module or subproject instead of the whole codebase, I'm not sure how to go about that.

I tried using the following properties in my SonarLint analyse Properties

sonar.projectKey    com.ttt.etrde.apps.servicemanager
sonar.projectKey    H:\Source\new_folder\ets\parent\services\svcmgr

but still Sonar ends up scanning the whole project all the way from ets level.

Comment: The primary use case for SonarLint is to find new issues in the files you're working in. Why analyze whole modules in SonarLint?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Because we have just started implementing SonarQube ans SonarLint, one reason is that we don't get module specifc reports in our SonarQube implementation, they are alphabetically arranged for the whole project, and we span over 2 million lines of code. We need to tell specific teams what is wrong with their code.
Second reason is, it is good to know what all errors exist in code that has not already been analysed.
I see we have option to scan the current file and option to scan the whole project, but no option for a given module.

Comment: ideally you would [edit] your question to include these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You can't

Long answer: You're not finding a way to restrict SonarLint analysis to a single module because that's not how it's intended to be used.

- The primary use case for SonarLint is to find new issues in the code you're working on as you type it. This happens automatically.
- The secondary use case is to see existing issues in the file(s) you're working on so you can fix them while you're at it. This is automatically visible in SonarLint's 'Current file' tab
- The tertiary use case is to double-check the files in your commit set before you commit them. This is visible in the 'Project files' tab.
- In a very distant 4th place is "Gee, I wonder if there are other issues in my project."

But really, this fourth use case (the one you want to expand) is only provided as a just-in-case for people who haven't yet adopted SonarQube. Since you *have*  adopted SonarQube Let's see how it addresses your situation:

> We need to tell specific teams what is wrong with their code.

Given that different teams are in charge of different modules, your best bet is to use SonarQube's drilldown capacity to see module home pages. To do that, go to the project's Code page, and use the module's "link out" icon

[image]

to get to a homepage for that module. There you can see all the same data you see for a project. This, then becomes where individual teams go.

> Second reason is, it is good to know what all errors exist in code that has not already been analysed.

From the module home page, you have the same issues drilldowns that are available on the project homepage.

Comment: You don't is very different from you can't, are you implying we cannot achieve this or we should not do this?
The reason I ask is that our SonarQube infra team is not able to achieve the module level filter. 
Is there a place where we can look at a sample Analyse Properties file so that we could at least get the SonarQube working in POC!

Comment: Both, actually.  What do you mean "not able to achieve the module level filter"? Achieve where? How?